# PCF Application Restart with Config Server update

Tags: .net-core, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, configserver

My .NET Core application is using Config Server which is referencing the configuration values which are stored in .yml at Git repo. 
Do we need to restart the application once the configuration value updated in Git to get the value to be reflected?

I wanted to understand is this the expected scenario or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how it works by default. You can configure whether the cofiguration will be fetched from git, or from the cloned config in the config-server's memory with the 'refreshRate' configuration.
See documentation for more informationt:
https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-0/common/config-server/configuring-with-git.html